# How can I split a string then place each part of the string in text boxes

Tags: c#, string, split, ip

```
string ip = ini.IniReadValue("Settings", "ip");
string[] ip2 = ip.Split('.');
foreach (var part in ip2)
{
    textBox3.Text = part[0].ToString();
    textBox4.Text = part[1].ToString();
    textBox5.Text = part[2].ToString();
    textBox6.Text = part[3].ToString();
}
```

Hi guys, my problem is that textBox3 just has a 1 in it, where as I want it to have 123
For the record, ip = 123.456.789.101 for testing purposes.

This is the result: 
[image: result].

Also it crashes when it sets textBox6: Index was outside the bounds of the array.

Answer (score 3):

Let's manually trace through your code:

1. `ip2` contains the array `{"123", "456", "789", "101"}`.
2. You are then iterating on the array in your `foreach` loop, so `part` becomes each of the strings `"123"`, `"456"`, `"789"`, `"101"` in turn.
3. Then you are indexing into the string (with square brackets), which accesses individual `char`s within the string. So in the first loop through,

   - `part[0]` is `'1'`,
   - `part[1]` is `'2'`,
   - `part[2]` is `'3'`, and
   - `part[3]` is beyond the bounds of the string (length=3).

Note your need to call `ToString()` was also a good indicator something was wrong.

Instead you want (without the `foreach` loop),

```
string ip = ini.IniReadValue("Settings", "ip");
string[] ip2 = ip.Split('.');
textBox3.Text = ip2[0];
textBox4.Text = ip2[1];
textBox5.Text = ip2[2];
textBox6.Text = ip2[3];
```

Answer (score 1):

Your logic is incorrect.

Every iteration of your `foreach` loop is an entire string. Therefore, when you do this:

```
part[NUMBER_HERE]
```

.. you're accessing a single character at that index of that string.

The `IndexOutOfBounds` error you're getting is because of what I said above. If you access the character at index 3 of a string with a length of 3 (indexes 0, 1 and 2).. it will be out of bounds.

You don't want a loop at all. Change your code to this:

```
string[] parts = ip.Split('.');
textBox3.Text = parts[0].ToString();
textBox4.Text = parts[1].ToString();
textBox5.Text = parts[2].ToString();
textBox6.Text = parts[3].ToString();
```

Now you have an actual string array that you are indexing.. not a single string.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `foreach` loop.

This line creates an array with each value in a new slot.

```
string[] ip2 = ip.Split('.');
```

However, this then takes every separate value in your array and accesses its n-th slot.

```
foreach (var part in ip2){
     textBox3.Text = part[0].ToString();
     textBox4.Text = part[1].ToString();
     textBox5.Text = part[2].ToString();
     textBox6.Text = part[3].ToString();
}
```

It will keep overwriting your data with the character on the given position (determined by index). The last entry is `101`, which is why the last values in the textboxes are `1`, `0` and `1`.
Just remove the loop and you're fine.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are iterating over the first result of the split. The array ip2 contains the results of the split (i.e. ip2[0]="123"). But then you write `part[0]`, and since part contains the first result of the split (in the first iteration anyway), part[0] now means the first character in "123" which is of course "1". Here's what you need to do:

```
string ip = ini.IniReadValue("Settings", "ip");
string[] ip2 = ip.Split('.');

textBox3.Text = ip2[0].ToString();
textBox4.Text = ip2[1].ToString();
textBox5.Text = ip2[2].ToString();
textBox6.Text = ip2[3].ToString();
```

Ideally you would need to check if the split returned enough results as well before assigning it to the textboxes.